# Why do async pipe nested within switch case never resolve?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am having trouble getting an observable that is nested within a switch case to resolve. Directly inside ngSwitch before the cases I can get the value for the observable. However once I am inside the switch case my value always returns null.

I have tried a few different things to resolve this with no progress. Perhaps I have a miss-understanding of how the async pipe works in angular templates?

```html
<!--template-->
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="(selectedFilterConfig$ | async)?.filterType">
  <p>{{(selectedFilterValueMap$ | async | json)}}</p> <!--This resolves.-->
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'select'">
    <p>List these...</p>
    <p>{{(selectedFilterValueMap$ | async | json)}}</p> <!--This always comes back null.-->
    <p *ngFor="let item of (selectedFilterValueMap$ | async)"> <!--So does this...-->
{{item.display}}</p>
  </div>
  <div *ngSwitchDefault>
    <p>Not a select!</p>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

```
/* Imports */

interface FilterColumnSelectItem {
  value: string;
  display: string;
}

export interface FilterSelection {
  filter: string;
  value: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-new-filters-dialog',
  styleUrls: ['./add-new-filters-dialog.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './add-new-filters-dialog.component.html',
})
export class AddNewFiltersDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  public newFilterForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    filterSelection: [''],
    filterValue: [''],
  });

  public filterSelectionFormValue$: Observable<string>;
  public filterValueFormValue$: Observable<string>;
  public tableColumnConfigs$: Observable<ColumnMeta[]>;
  public filterSelectionFormControl: AbstractControl;
  public filterValueFormControl: AbstractControl;
  public selectedFilterConfig$: Observable<FilterConfig>;
  public selectedFilterMeta$: Observable<ColumnMeta>;
  public selectedFilterValueMap$: Observable<FilterColumnSelectItem[]>;

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddNewFiltersDialogComponent>,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
   ) {}

   public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.filterSelectionFormControl = this.newFilterForm.get('filterSelection');
    this.filterValueFormControl = this.newFilterForm.get('filterValue');

    this.filterSelectionFormValue$ = this.filterSelectionFormControl.valueChanges.pipe(val => val);
    this.filterValueFormValue$ = this.filterValueFormControl.valueChanges.pipe(val => val);

    this.selectedFilterMeta$ = combineLatest(this.tableColumnConfigs$, this.filterSelectionFormValue$).pipe(
      map(([metas, filterSelection]) =>
        metas.find(meta => meta.columnName === filterSelection)));

     this.selectedFilterConfig$ = this.selectedFilterMeta$.pipe(
       map(meta => meta != null ? meta.filterConfig : null));

     this.selectedFilterValueMap$ = this.selectedFilterConfig$.pipe(
       map(config => !!config.filterSelectOptions ? config.filterSelectOptions : null))
       .pipe(map(selectionItems => {
         if (!selectionItems) {
           return null;
         }

         return orderBy(selectionItems, 'priority')
           .map(selectionItem => ({value: selectionItem.value, display: selectionItem.display}));
       }));
   }

  /* Rest of component */
}
```

I want be able to get the results for `selectedFilterValueMap$` after the switch case has passed.

Comment: Can you provide details around how you have `selectedFilterValueMap$` set up in your component?

Comment: you can check whether this.selectedFilterMeta$  is firing , it seems it's your source observable

Comment: @FanCheung it does fire in the switch statement and I get data back. However within the switch case it does not fire and I get no data.